# Connecting existing document library to sharepoint site

Tags: sharepoint, office365, power-automate

I was experimenting with MS Flow in Office 365, trying to automatically extract info from excel files. However, it turns out we made some "design error" in our sharepoint structure.

We have multiple central document libraries that are only linked to the Onedrive for Business environment and not connected to a Sharepoint site. (The latter turns out to be necessary for MS flow.) Is it possible to link existing document libraries to a sharepoint site?

EDITS:
Some background: within onedrive for business we have created multiple document libraries. See the screenshot below (blacked out are the ones we created).
[Screenshot of Onedrive for Business "Site Contents"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkeGy.png)

Using MS flow I want to extract info from some of the Excel sheets in those doc libs. However,  when using the wizards, I can only access files in document libraries that are created from a Sharepoint site (mine were apparently created directly in the OnedrivefB environment) or the main document library from OnedrivefB (as shown below; when choosing Onedrive, the File wizard only shows the files in the 'Documents' doc lib as also listed in the previous screenshot. [Screenshot from Flow wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gh0cU.png)

Elsewhere, I was told I should connect the document libraries we created to a Sharepoint site. But this person couldn't tell me how... Other suggestions are of course welcome as well!

Thanks, J

For completeness:
[Step 1 in the wizard, showing sharepoint sites and onedrive for business](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEmVM.png)

[Step 2 in the wizard, showing options when choosing for OdfB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I3gP.png)

[Step 3 in the wizard, only showing files from the document library called "Documents" in the first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aK7EL.png)

[A screenshot from one such document library with the Excel I am trying to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vVG5.png)

Answer (score 0):

Both OneDrive for Business and Sharepoint sites can be connected to MS Flow. If you are looking for the connection with OneDrive for Business, check the below link for triggers and sample templates

https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_onedriveforbusiness/onedrive-for-business/

Sharepoint -

https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/shared_sharepointonline/sharepoint/

EDIT:
To access an Excel file in an OneDrivefB folder, browse and select the excel using file option. It will list all the folders in your OneDrive library.

[image]

.Second screenshot which you attached is sharepoint assets. they cant be linked to OneDrive. It can only be linked to sharepoint sites

Comment: thanks for your reply. Let me give a bit more background. I want to use the Excel action "get a row". Unfortunately, that action does not allow me access to secondary OnedrivefB document libraries. See also the following 2 screenshots. This one shows you can only get the main document library under Onedrive for Business: https://lith.tc/2ursasW (named Documents in the next screenshot). This one shows the actual list of document libraries: https://lith.tc/2JkFmFo. None of those show up. I was advised to connect the document libraries to a Sharepoint site to resolve this. But don't know how.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your OneDrive folder containing that excel file? Check the Edited answer on accessing the onedrive folders

Comment: Thanks again for your time Dinesh! I have edited the question; hopefully this provides the info needed! If not, please let me know!